# Action in terms of momentum $p$ and distance $L$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, action

> Calculate the stationary action for the real trajectory of a (non-relativistic) free particle travelling from $1$ to $2$, see [Fig 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBdeo.png) . Express your answer in terms of momentum $p$ and distance $L$.

Here is my work so far:

For a free particle, there is no potential or force. By Newton's First Law, its motion is uniform along

a straight line. Hence its action can be expressed as  $$S_0 =\int_1^2 dt \frac{m}{2} \dot x^2 = \frac{m}{2} {v^2} \int_1^2 dt = T(2 - 1)$$

This is indeed the product of conserved kinetic energy and the time that has passed during the

motion. It is however can be recalculated in a slightly different way

$$ S_0 = \frac{mv}{2} = \int_1^2 dt \space v = \frac{mv}{2} \int_{x_1}^{x_2} dx = \frac{p}{2} ({x_2} - {x_1}).$$

Since the question asks to answer in terms of both momentum and distance. my final equation for $S_0$ only has the momentum, how can I do it in a way so that the equation has both momentum and distance?